# Contributions of light relics to the effective number of neutrino species

Tags: cosmology

These [slides](https://indico.cern.ch/event/618499/contributions/2573145/attachments/1510183/2354710/Meyers_-_CMB_and_Light_Degrees_of_Freedom.pdf) show that contribution $\Delta N_{\rm eff}$ to the "effective number of neutrino species" $N_{\rm eff}$ by light relics can be computed by first noting that
\begin{equation}
g_*(T_{\nu{\rm -decoupling}}) = 2 + \frac{7}{8}(2 + 2 + 2\times 3) = \frac{43}{4}
.
\end{equation}
Using conservation of comoving entropy ($g_*aT = {\rm const.}$) it then follows that
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{T_{\rm relic}}{T_\nu} \right)^3 = \frac{g_*(T_{\nu{\rm -decoupling}})}{g_*(T_F)} = \frac{43}{4}
\end{equation}
where $T_F$ is the decoupling temperature of the light thermal relic. This formula is a bit confusing to me since is suggests that $T_F > T_{\nu{\rm -decoupling}}$ while later the slides linked indicate that it is possible for the decoupling temperature to occur after neutrino decoupling. The notation is also a bit confusing; shouldn't $T_F = T_{\rm relic}$?

Any help would be appreciated!